# How to determine which one of the following groups is isomorphic to another group?

Tags: group-theory

Let $\bf{Z}_{35}^*$ denote the group consisting of elements $\{x \in \{0,1,2,...,34\}:\text{hcf}(x,35)=1\}$  with operation multiplication modulo $35$. We have $\bf{Z}_{35}^*$ is finite and abelian therefore it is isomorphic to exactly one product of cyclic groups where the order of each group in the product divides the order of the next element in the product.

I want to find this group.

So far I have concluded $|{\bf{Z}_{35}^*}|=\phi(35)=24$ where $\phi$ is Euler's Totient function.

So we have $\bf{Z}_{35}^*$ is isomorphic to one of the groups of order 24 with structure as described above.

There are precisely $3$ groups with this property:

$$\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_6,~\Bbb{Z}_2\times\Bbb{Z}_{12},~\Bbb{Z}_{24}$$

How would I go about finding which one of these three our group is isomorphic to?

I don't want a full answer maybe just a hint to push me in the right direction.

Any hints.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of hcf?

Comment: Also in $\mathbb{Z}_{35}^{\star}$, shouldn't you be working mod $35$ instead of mod $7$.

Comment: None of them is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_{24}}$. We say the following:
$\mathbb{Z_n} \times \mathbb{Z_m}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_{nm}} $ iff $gcd(n,m)=1$

Comment: Yes my bad that's a typo it should be mod $35$

Comment: @Ninja hcf is highest common factor it is the same as gcd if you are familiar with that. And I think you are not understanding the question I am asking what $\bf{Z}_{35}^*$ is isomorphic to. (It is isomorphic to one of the three groups I listed).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: It comes down to the question: "Does it contain an element of order 24? And, if not, does it contain an element of order 12?"

Comment: Sorry I don't see how that would help me? If it contains an element of order $24$ then it would have to be isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_{24}$ since that is the only one with elements of order $24$? Is that right? If so how can I answer the questions you pose? Do I just need to brute force it or is there a slicker argument I'm not seeing? I don't fancy going through $24$ total elements and checking if one of them has order $24$.

Comment: For example, you could try searching for an element of order 3 and then its "square root" (order 6) etc. This is the quickest way I can think of.